# Linear Model Predictive Control Optimization Running Slowly

Tags: python, drake

I am attempting to implement linear MPC of a quadrotor in Drake.

To start with, I have generated a simple desired trajectory moving only in the z-direction using the following parameters

```
#calculate optimal trajectory and simulation
initial_state = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# target state for trajectory optimization
final_state = [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
# limit of thrust force for each individual propellor
thrust_limit = 10.0

#we want to have an odd number
num_time_samples = 40
# number of samples into future we will run trajectory optimization
time_horizon = 40

initial_thrust = [0., 0., 0., 0.]
time_step = 0.1
```

I have instantiated my MathematicalProgram in the contstructor of my MpcController Class

```
class MpcController(VectorSystem):

def __init__(self, quadrotor_plant, init_state, target_state, time_horizon, 
            max_time_samples, thrust_limit, obstacle_list, initial_thrust, time_step):

    # define this system as having 12 inputs and 4 outputs
    VectorSystem.__init__(self, 12, 4)
    self.quadrotor_plant = quadrotor_plant
    self.init_state = init_state
    self.target_state = target_state
    self.time_horizon = time_horizon
    self.max_time_samples = max_time_samples
    self.thrust_limit = thrust_limit
    self.obstacle_list = obstacle_list
    self.current_step = 0

    self.current_output = inital_thrust
    
    self.time_step = time_step

    # initialize optimization
    self.prog = MathematicalProgram()
```

I have connected instantiated and connectedmy MPC controller to my quadrotor plant like so:

```
# define the quadrotor plant using drake built in quadrotor plant class
# this is a System, not a MultiBodyPlant
quadrotor_plant = QuadrotorPlant()
quadrotor_plant = builder.AddSystem(quadrotor_plant)

mpc_controller = MpcController(quadrotor_plant, initial_state, final_state, time_horizon, 
num_time_samples, thrust_limit, obstacles, initial_thrust, time_step)
mpc_controller = builder.AddSystem(mpc_controller)

# connect the MPC controller to the quadrotor
builder.Connect(mpc_controller.get_output_port(0), quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0))
builder.Connect(quadrotor_plant.get_output_port(0), mpc_controller.get_input_port(0))
```

Finally, I have my linear MPC trajectory optimization, which is executed at each step of my simulation.

```
def DoCalcVectorOutput(self, context, inp, state, output):

    # quadrotor_mutable_context = self.quadrotor_plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(self.sim_context)
    quadrotor_context = self.quadrotor_plant.CreateDefaultContext()

    # fix input port of quadrotor with output of MPC controller, in order to perform linearization
    # this is the output from the previous iteration of the sim
    self.quadrotor_plant.get_input_port(0).FixValue(quadrotor_context, self.current_output)

    # input into the controller is the state of the quadrotor
    # set the context equal to the current state
    quadrotor_context.SetContinuousState(inp)
    current_state = inp

    ##################
    # Linearize system dynamics - Take first order taylor series expansions of system
    # around the operating point defined by quadrotor context
    ##################
    eq_check_tolerance = 10e6 # we do not need to be at an equilibrium point
    linear_quadrotor = Linearize(self.quadrotor_plant, quadrotor_context, \
    equilibrium_check_tolerance = eq_check_tolerance )

    #### get A & B matrices of linearized continuous dynamics
    A = linear_quadrotor.A()
    B = linear_quadrotor.B()

    # print(f"len A = {len(A)}")
    # print(f"len B = {len(B)}")
    # print(f"A = {A}")
    # print(f"B = {B}")

    # number of time steps in optimization should decrease as we get closer to target
    # num_samples = min(self.time_horizon, self.max_time_samples - self.current_step +1)
    num_samples = self.time_horizon

    # print(f"cur_quad_state = {current_state}")
    # print(f"quadrotor current input = {self.current_output}")
    # print(f"num_samples = {num_samples}")
    # print(f"target_state = {self.target_state}")

    # optimization variables
    # input to controller is state, x
    self.x = self.prog.NewContinuousVariables(self.time_horizon + 1, 12, 'state')
    # output from controller is thrust, u
    self.u = self.prog.NewContinuousVariables(self.time_horizon, 4, 'thrust')

    ## Add starting state constraint based on current state
    self.prog.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(current_state, current_state, self.x[0,:])


    ### add quadratic cost on state error ###
    Q = 100000*np.diag([100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,10.,10.,10.,10.,10.,10.])
    #### Add quadratic cost on input effort ###
    R = np.diag([1.,1.,1.,1.,])

    for t in range(num_samples):
        
        # calculate residual using Implicit Euler integration
        residuals = self.quadrotor_discrete_dynamics(A, B, self.x[t], 
        self.x[t+1], self.u[t], self.time_step)
        for residual in residuals:
            self.prog.AddLinearConstraint(residual == 0)

        # calculate quadratic state error cost
        # error  = self.x[t] - self.target_state
        # self.prog.AddCost(error.T.dot(Q.dot(error)) )
        self.prog.AddQuadraticErrorCost(Q, self.target_state, self.x[t])

        self.prog.AddCost(self.u[t].dot(R.dot(self.u[t])))


    #### Define initial guess trajectory by linearly interpolating between current state and target 
    initial_x_trajectory = self.generate_initial_guess(current_state, self.target_state, 
        num_samples, self.time_step )

    self.prog.SetInitialGuess(self.x, initial_x_trajectory)


    # print("running solver")
    result = Solve(self.prog)
    assert (result.is_success())

    # # retrieve optimal solution
    u_trajectory = result.GetSolution(self.u)
    # x_trajectory = result.GetSolution(x)
    

    #### set output to first step of thrust trajectory ###
    print(u_trajectory[0])
    output[:] = u_trajectory[0]

    # output[:] = [10.,10.,10.,10.]
    self.current_output = output
    print(output)

    ##### increment current timestep
    self.current_step += 1
```

The quadrotor discrete dynamics and inital guess methods are defined here:

```
    def quadrotor_discrete_dynamics(self, A, B, state, state_next, thrust, time_step):
    '''This method assumes quadrotor dynamics have been linearized, and A & B 
    matrices have been passed in from linear quadrotor'''

    # continuous-time dynamics evaluated at the next time step
    # in the form state_dot_continous = f(state, thrust)
    state_dot_continous = A.dot(state_next) + B.dot(thrust)

    # implicit-Euler state update
    # enforce x[n+1] = x[n] + f(x[n], u[n]) * time_step
    residuals = state_next - state - time_step * state_dot_continous

    return residuals


# generate initial guess of x trajectory by interpolating between current state and target
def generate_initial_guess(self, current_state, target_state, num_samples, time_interval ):
    # np.random.seed(0)

    time_limits = [0., num_samples * time_interval ]
    state_samples = np.column_stack((self.init_state, self.target_state))
    initial_x_trajectory = PiecewisePolynomial.FirstOrderHold(time_limits, state_samples)

    # sample state on the time grid and add small random noise
    x_trajectory_guess = np.vstack([initial_x_trajectory.value(t * time_interval).T for t in range(num_samples + 1)])
    # x_trajectory_guess += np.random.rand(*x_trajectory_guess.shape) * 5e-6

    return x_trajectory_guess
```

When I simulate this system, the MPC optimization converges to the desired result, but the simulation runs incredibly slowly. Have I defined my costs / constraints in a way that would make things difficult for the solver?

Are there any tricks to making these optimizations execute more quickly in Drake?

Here are the printouts of the execution times for the linearization, program setup and solver portions of DoCalcVectorOutput

[image: Execution Time for linearization, program setup, and solve steps]

The solve time dominates the execution time and increases with each iteration of the sim.

Comment: It would be more informative if you could let us know which part of the code is slow. In DoCalcVectorOutput it does several things: 1) linearize the dynamics. 2) construct a mathematical program representing the MPC 3) solve the mathematical program. Could you time each part and report the individual time? You can also check what solver is used by doing `print(result.get_solver_id())`.

Comment: After printing the timing of each portion, it is clear that the solver time dominates. The solve time is increasing with each iteration of the sim. Have you seen this before? Could I be accumulating decision variables somehow?

Comment: First I would advice to use a different solver, like Gurobi or Mosek. These commencial solvers typically runs much faster than OSQP. You can follow the tutorial https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/mathematical_program.ipynb, in the section "manually choosing a solver".

Second I would suggest to warm-start your program. Namely take the solution (x_tape, u_tape) of the previous call of DoCalcVectorOutput, shift them by one time index, and then set the initial guess of the current program to that shifted version of the previous solution.

Comment: Thirdly, your time horizon is quite long, do you need that long horizon? Moreover, your program has a lot of constraints (with the dynamics constraints x[n+1] = A * x[n] + B * u[n]), I would suggest to re-formulate the problem and only use u[1], u[2], ..., u[nT] as decision variables and compute x_tape from u_tape.

Comment: Based on a quick look at the code, it looks like you are creating `self.prog` once, and then adding a new problem into it on every update?  Is it possible that by timestep 10 you are solving 10 optimization problems as one big optimization?

You should either make a new prog each time or (better) consider using `UpdateCoefficients` on the cost/constraint classes to avoid reallocating the entire program.